# Is there any way to read file as a File object in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

I want to get local file as a file object no Buffer, I need File{} object. readSync giving me Buffer.

Comment: Do you mean [this kind of File object](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#file-section)? Which is designed for web applications? Not Node?

Comment: This reads like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You probably don't need a File object. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Local file on a client's computer, or local server file? Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to mean the file of my project. Everytime a service generate json file, i want to read the file as a File object where all metadata includes

Comment: ```
File {     "clientName": "Shrikanta-mazumder.jpg",     "extname": "jpg",     "fileName": null,     "fieldName": "profile_image",     "tmpPath": "/tmp/ab-e9bfe920-fac7-491f-b4ff-917ac1d408b9.tmp",     "headers": {         "content-disposition": "form-data; name=\"profile_image\"; filename=\"Shrikanta-mazumder.jpg\"",         "content-type": "image/jpeg"     },     "size": 1050365,     "type": "image",     "subtype": "jpeg",     "status": "consumed",     "error": {}  }
```

I want to read project file like this.

Comment: @shrikantamazumder — Well, that's not how readFile works. You'll need to get the various bits of data you are interested in through other APIs.

Answer (score -2):

According to [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilepath-options-callback) :

```
fs.readFile(path[, options])

 options <Object> | <string>
      encoding <string> | <null> Default: null
```

> If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.

Solution : specify an encoding.

```
fs.readFile(path, { encoding: "utf8"})
```

Comment: No. this not return File object like sent from client. it returns Buffer or content or the file. I nee File object where all metadata of the file is included

Comment: "File object like sent from client"? What do you mean? You said you wanted to read a local file.

Comment: i want to get like this

```File {
    "clientName": "Shrikanta-mazumder.jpg",
    "extname": "jpg",
    "fileName": null,
    "fieldName": "profile_image",
    "tmpPath": "/tmp/ab-e9bfe920-fac7-491f-b4ff-917ac1d408b9.tmp",
    "headers": {
        "content-disposition": "form-data; name=\"profile_image\"; filename=\"Shrikanta-mazumder.jpg\"",
        "content-type": "image/jpeg"
    },
    "size": 1050365,
    "type": "image",
    "subtype": "jpeg",
    "status": "consumed",
    "error": {}

}```

Comment: "I want to get" from where? Who sends the file? From the front-end? With an ajax request? If so how do you read the file in the front-end? Your question is extremely vague and unclear. You need to provide a specific problem and explanation with the relevant code, not just "I want file object".